# Pasar array dinamico por AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

**EDITADO**

Estoy tratando de enviar los siguiente datos con AJAX

```
var datosInsert = JSON.stringify({
        'datosCarga': valoresEntrada, //[1,2,3]
        'loteCaja': fieldLote,   //101
        'cajaLote': numeroCaja //1
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "views/ajax/OITSave.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: datosInsert,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        //dataType: "json",
        success: function(respuesta) {
            console.log("Se devolvio: ", respuesta);
        }
    });
```

Los estoy recibiendo y "asignando" de la siguiente forma al archivo donde dirijo el ajax

```
<?php

require_once "../../controllers/OIT.php";
require_once "../../models/OIT.php";


#CLASES
#**********************************************************************

class Ajax{


   #RECIBE DATOS PARA INGRESO CAJA

   public $loteIngreso;
   public $cajaIngreso;
   public $recorrido;
   public $valoresCaja=[];

   public function agregarEnCaja(){
        echo $loteIngreso;
   }

}

#OBJETOS
#************************************************************************

if(isset($_POST['loteCaja'])){
    $c = new Ajax();
    $c -> loteIngreso = $_POST['loteCaja'];
    $c -> cajaIngreso =  $_POST['cajaLote'];
    $c -> valoresCaja = $_POST['datosCarga'];
    $c -> agregarEnCaja();


}
?>
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto la respuesta es vacia.
Esta bien la forma como envie los datos? Si es asi, esta bien la forma en la que recibo la datos?

De verdad, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es necesario `parsear` con `JSON.stringify` para enviar los datos, puede enviar simplemente como `clave : valor` directamente en la función `Ajax` de la siguiente forma .

```
$.ajax({
    url: "views/ajax/OITSave.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
    'datosCarga': valoresEntrada, //[1,2,3]
    'loteCaja': fieldLote,   //101
    'cajaLote': numeroCaja//1
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(respuesta) {
        console.log("Se devolvio: ", respuesta);
    }
});
```

Luego pasando al código `PHP` tiene solo un pequeño detalle es en la función `agregarEnCaja` intenta retornar un atributo de su clase por lo que tal y como está fallará ya que para acceder debe hacerlo primero a `$this` para referirse al objeto actual y luego a su atributo.

```
public function agregarEnCaja(){
    echo $this->loteIngreso;
}
```